# i18n search using tire and Globalize3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, internationalization, tire, i18n-gem, globalize3

i have a site that uses globalize3 gem (https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3) and i'm currently adding the Tire gem to make site search.

How do i do to Index a table translations depending on the actual locale? right now the model that gets indexed only does with the default locale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to index all the translations:

```
class Centre < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  mapping do
    indexes :title_en, :as => lambda { |post| I18n.locale = :en; post.title }
    indexes :title_es, :as => lambda { |post| I18n.locale = :es; post.title }
    indexes :title_jp, :as => lambda { |post| I18n.locale = :jp; post.title }
  end

end
```

This can become cumbersome if you support a lot of languages for a lot of attributes, you might have to resort to meta-programming:

```
class Centre < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  mapping do
    %w[en it jp].each do |locale|
      %w[title text].each do |attribute|
        class_eval<<-RUBY
          indexes :#{attribute}_#{locale}, :as => lambda { |post| I18n.locale = :#{locale}; post.#{attribute} }
        RUBY
      end
    end
  end

end
```

I didn't test the above code, it's just to give an idea, so make sure you understand it and it works before using it in your project, otherwise BAD THINGS WILL HAPPEN™.

Comment: got it, thanks for the approach, i was thinking on modifying the gem to consider the table _translations to the search, but this looks ok as well. thanks!

Comment: Note that the `I18n.locale` setting is global, so a request might end up with a different locale than it started with. Consider resetting the locale at the end of each lambda.