# Globalize Tire ElasticSearch and accent folding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

After following the advices on this question:

[i18n search using tire and Globalize3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951348/i18n-search-using-tire-and-globalize3)

I indexed my title and body fields. The problem is that while the indexing works, when I conduct a search, it does not fold the accents. I configured the searched model like so:

```
settings index: { analysis: {
                    analyzer: {
                      index_analyzer: {
                        tokenizer: "whitespace",
                        filter: ["asciifolding", "lowercase", "snowball"]
                      },
                      search_analyzer: {
                        tokenizer: "whitespace",
                        filter: ["asciifolding", "lowercase", "snowball"]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
```

So why isnt Tire using these analyzers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you applying those analyzers to any field?  Are you searching on that field, or on the `_all` field?

If you intend to use those analyzers as the default analyzers for the whole index, then they should be named `default_index` and `default_search`.  In fact they're both the same, so you could just specify the analyzer once as `default`.

This is how Elasticsearch determines which analyzer to use at index time:

- the `index_analyzer` defined in the field mapping, else
- the `analyzer` defined in the field mapping, else
- the analyzer defined in the `_analyzer` field of the document, else
- the default `index_analyzer` for the `type`, which defaults to
- the default `analyzer` for the `type`, which defaults to
- the analyzer named `default_index` in the index settings, which defaults to
- the analyzer named `default` in the index settings, which defaults to
- the analyzer named `default_index` at node level, which defaults to
- the analyzer named `default` at node level, which defaults to
- the `standard` analyzer

and at search time:

- the `analyzer` defined in the query itself, else
- the `search_analyzer` defined in the field mapping, else
- the `analyzer` defined in the field mapping, else
- the default `search_analyzer` for the `type`, which defaults to
- the default `analyzer` for the `type`, which defaults to
- the analyzer named `default_search` in the index settings, which defaults to
- the analyzer named `default` in the index settings, which defaults to
- the analyzer named `default_search` at node level, which defaults to
- the analyzer named `default` at node level, which defaults to
- the `standard` analyzer